# How to return output of the new wp gallery block for automatically Link images To Media file

Tags: php, gallery, block-editor

Sorry for the repeated questions but I didn't get any solution yet!

I'm stuck with that!!

I mange a multi writers blog, and all our users uploading some gallery images, and they didn't know the difference between (attachment, media file or none). I found solution to hide the linking panel, but I am editing all the published posts to change the gallery images link to file "manually". :(

[image]

Before WordPress version 5 I was linked all gallery images to "file" automatically by using this filter below.

```
add_filter( 'shortcode_atts_gallery',
    function( $out ){
        $out['link'] = 'file'; 
        return $out;
    }
);
```

But after WP 5+ how can I make it to work again? I really need to link all gallery images to "media file" automatically!

I hope someone will help me or even giving me the right way.

Thanks for your time.